# Operator norm linear regression

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Given matrix $\mathbf{X}\in R^{d\times r}$ and $\mathbf{A}\in R^{d\times n}$, the opertor norm regression is defined as follows $\mathbf{Y}=argmin_{Y\in \mathbb R^{r\times n}}\|\mathbf{XY-A}\|_2$

where $\|\mathbf{A}\|_2$ is the operator norm of $\mathbf{A}$ i.e. maximum singular value of $\mathbf{A}$. Is there a closed-form expression for $\mathbf{Y}$?
Any help, comments, references are greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Is $\mathbf{U}$ supposed to be $\mathbf{X}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An attempt: let us write $X = U \Sigma V^\top$ for the thin SVD of $X$ (without loss of generality, assume $X$ has full column rank $r$; otherwise, adjust accordingly). In the above decomposition, $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}$ is invertible, $U^\top U = I$ and $V V^\top = V^\top V = I$, with $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}, \; V \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}$. Then, applying the [Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Proof_of_Eckart%E2%80%93Young%E2%80%93Mirsky_theorem_(for_spectral_norm)), which says that $A_r$, the rank-$r$ truncated svd of $A$, is the closest matrix of rank $r$ to $A$ (measured the $\| \cdot \|_2$ norm), we simply have to solve

$$
X Y = A_r \Leftrightarrow U \Sigma V^\top Y = A_r \Rightarrow
Y = V \Sigma^{-1} U^\top A_r.
$$

I don't really have the time to check if this is the unique solution, but it gives you the minimal objective value.

Comment: Putting aside possible issues with the column rank of $X$, this solution is unique iff $\sigma_r>\sigma_{r+1}$, so there is a unique choice of the truncated SVD.